# How to save response data in a variable or state in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, trello

i'm trying to use [trello-web](https://github.com/fiatjaf/trello-web) in react.
in the docs it say:

When you have a token, you can do .get, .put, .post and .del, for example:

```
trello.get('/1/boards').then(console.log)
```

and everything works fine (with console.log).

But if i want save the response in a variable what i have to change in this line of code to use it in my component?

I dont understand that

```
.then(console.log)
```

print in my console and so i cant save it to reuse correctly.
If someone help me to understand.. thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u are using react u can make a state in component eg.

```
[myData, setMyData] = useState();
```

Now you can handle incoming data by
trello.get('/1/boards')
returns you a "Promise", you can handle it in two ways

1.

```
var data = async trello.get('/1/boards')
setMyData(data)
```

2. 

```
trello.get('/1/boards').then( (data) => { setMyData(data) } )
```

Answer (score 2):

`.then(console.log)` is a shorthand of `.then(event => console.log(event))` (or rather, `data`). You can write your own function that takes that event as an argument, then do whatever you want with it, for example:

```
.then(save)

function save(event) {
    //do stuff with the event
}
```

I know you said React, but this should get you going.